# Ternary operator for comparsion not giving accurate result

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I am using ternary operator for comparing and calculating but it is not giving desired result.
What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
int x = 600000;
x = (x > 250000 && x < 500000 ? 
        (x > 500000 && x < 1000000 ? 
            (x > 1000000 ? 
                x = (x / 100) * 30 : 
                x = (x / 100) * 20) : 
            x = (x / 100) * 10):
        x);
```

I want to achieve this:

```
if (x > 250000 && x < 500000)
{
    x = (x / 100) * 10;
}
else if (x > 500000 && x < 1000000)
{
    x = (x / 100) * 20;
}
else if (x > 1000000)
{
    x = (x / 100) * 30;
}
```

Comment: In this case, the if blocks are so much more readable, I wouldn't bother with the complex ternary operator, but just my 2 cents.

Comment: Then why don't you use second part? It is more readable then first one.

Comment: if you check it in reverse order you won't have to verify the upper bounds

Comment: Why would you want to kill the readability ? Also you do know that the logic above has holes. If the in is 500000 or 1000000 your ITEs will never be correct.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "improving" working code.

Comment: I am building some engine where i cannot use if condition because it does not support, i can only use ternary operator..

Comment: It could be because these two statements are not exactly equivalent: check again your ternary logic (and, btw, consider the readability recommendation given to you in previous comments). Best regards,

Comment: By the way, before it is closed, if it's not working it's because you inverted the statements. It's `(something) ? statement : else`. Looks like you did `(something) ? else : statement`.

Comment: I am just curious: why "some engine" can't use "if"? it sounds strange that it does not "support" "if" - it looks more like a constraint imposed by a teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = (x > 250000 && x < 500000) ? (x / 100) * 10 : ((x > 500000 && x < 1000000) ? (x / 100) * 20 : ((x > 1000000) ? (x / 100) * 30 : x));
```

Ternary operator of the form `(conditional) ? expr1 : expr2` should be read as `if conditional then expr1 otherwise expr2`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first warn you that long ternary operations like this is usually not prescribed as it's only going to cause problems in the future if there's any modifications. Nevertheless, the following will do the required:

```
int x = 600000;
x = (x > 250000 && x < 500000) ? ((x / 100) * 10): ((x > 500000 && x < 1000000) ? ((x / 100) * 20): (x > 1000000) ? ((x / 100) * 30):x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're cascading the `if-then-else` wrong. An `else if` is a part of the `else`. The expression is thus:

```
x = (x > 250000 && x < 500000) ?
    (x / 100) * 10 :
    ((x > 500000 && x < 1000000) ?
        (x / 100) * 20 :
        ((x > 1000000) ?
            (x / 100) * 30 ) :
            x
        )
    )
);
```

But I don't see why you want to use ternary operators for such complex statements. They don't yield any performance gain. Ternary operators are mainly used for small expressions with no (or not much) cascading.

**Background information**

An `else if` is actually an `if` cascaded into an `else` thus:

```
if (x > 250000 && x < 500000) {
    x = (x / 100) * 10;
}
else if (x > 500000 && x < 1000000) {
    x = (x / 100) * 20;
}
else if (x > 1000000) {
    x = (x / 100) * 30;
}
```

Actually reads:

```
if (x > 250000 && x < 500000) {
    x = (x / 100) * 10;
}
else {
    if (x > 500000 && x < 1000000) {
        x = (x / 100) * 20;
    }
    else {
        if (x > 1000000) {
            x = (x / 100) * 30;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you indent your code, it makes it a bit easer to see what's going on

```
x = (x > 250000 && x < 500000
        ? (x > 500000 && x < 1000000
            ? (x > 1000000
                ? x = (x / 100) * 30
                : x = (x / 100) * 20)
            : x = (x / 100) * 10)
        :x);
```

This translates to the following `if-else` statements:

```
if (x > 250000 && x < 500000)
{
    if (x > 500000 && x < 1000000)
    {
        if (x > 1000000)
        {
            x = (x / 100) * 30;
        }
        else
        {
            x = (x / 100) * 20;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        x = (x / 100) * 10;
    }
}
else
{
    x = x;
}
```

Which it is obvious to see that if `x > 250000 && x < 500000` is met then it will never get to the second if statement.